# Get a Duration from the unit

Tags: luxon

Let's say that I know an unit and an amount of this unit. Is there a way to get a Duration object from it?

Something like `Duration.fromUnitAmount(unit: DurationUnit, amount: number): Duration` or `DurationUnit.getDuration(amount: number): Duration`, or to build a `Duration` object from an object such as `{ unit: myUnit, amount: myAmount }`.

### Edit

I've made a function for it, but I wanted to know if something was built-in for this. Here is the function:

```js
    static getDurationFromAmountOfUnit(unit: DurationUnit, amount: number) {
        switch (unit) {
            case 'years':
            case 'year':
                return Duration.fromObject({year: amount});
            case 'quarters':
            case 'quarter':
                return Duration.fromObject({quarter: amount});
            case 'months':
            case 'month':
                return Duration.fromObject({month: amount});
            case 'weeks':
            case 'week':
                return Duration.fromObject({week: amount});
            case 'days':
            case 'day':
                return Duration.fromObject({day: amount});
            case 'hours':
            case 'hour':
                return Duration.fromObject({hour: amount});
            case 'minutes':
            case 'minute':
                return Duration.fromObject({minute: amount});
            case 'seconds':
            case 'second':
                return Duration.fromObject({second: amount});
            case 'milliseconds':
            case 'millisecond':
                return Duration.fromObject({millisecond: amount});
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want us to tell you exactly? this is a very vague question.

Comment: @vaira I would like a way to get an object from Luxon representing a duration from an amount of duration unit and a unit. If there is no way without making my own function, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

```js
import { Duration, DurationUnit } from 'luxon';

function getDuration(unit: DurationUnit, amount: number) {
  return Duration.fromObject({
    [unit]: amount,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well and is way simpler than my solution

Comment: Hey @nkoniishvt , if this answer helped you. Please accept it. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157936)